# Angular JS -> cannot read property

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

> Cannot read property 'result' of undefined

Angular Function :

```
.controller('forgotCtrl', function($scope,$http,$ionicPopup,$state,$ionicHistory) {
    $scope.forgot=function(data1){
        var link1 = 'http://localhost/uxo_data/forgot.php';
        var json10 = {n : data1.mobile };
        $http.post(link1, { data1: json10 })
        .then(function (res){
            $scope.response = res.data1.result; 
            console.log(res.data1.result);
            if($scope.response.created=="1"){   
                $scope.title="Password Reset!";
                $scope.template="Please Check your associated Email Account!";

                //no back option
                $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                    disableAnimate: true,
                    disableBack: true
                });
                $state.go('login', {}, {location: "replace", reload: true});

            }else if($scope.response.exists=="1"){
                $scope.title="Failed";
                $scope.template="Number you entered doesn't exist";

            }else{
                $scope.title="Failed";
                $scope.template="Contact Our Technical Team";
            }

            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: $scope.title,
                    template: $scope.template
            });


        });

    }
})
```

Output i get from rest-api is :

```
{"result":{"created": "0" , "exists": "1" }}
```

I Checked in Web Debugging tool, php code is working fine and giving above response as output.

Comment: Try for console.log(res.data);

Comment: There are only two parts in your code where you attempt to access a *"result"* property and they both reference the same thing. Your very first check should have been that the object you were attempting to access was referenced correctly. `res.data1` is undefined, so why do you think that might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this line from

```
 $scope.response = res.data1.result;
```

to

```
$scope.response = res.data.result;
```

The response will have a data object which you are accessing incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(res.data1.result); // => data1 is undefined
```

try below code:

```
console.log(res.data.result);
```